# Obtain primary key of entity whose state is Added

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Problem**

I am implementing a UnitOfWork and a Repository style data access layer for my web application. I want to audit changes to the database using a custom table I have made. The problem occurs when a new item is added to the context. The item is added to the context, however `SaveChanges()` method has not been called so the entity is still in the `Added` state. This means that is has not been assigned a primary key, which means I can not create an audit record and calling `SaveChanges()` from the repository would violate the repository coding style. Is there a way to get the primary key of an entity in the added state?

**Attempted Solution**

The only solution that I can think of is to use random GUIDs so that the client can generate them. I am a little hesitant because I have heard that using random GUIDs as the identity field can be costly.

**Code**

```
//Method in my repository class
public void Insert(T entity)
{
    //Adds the entity the context
    dbSet.Add(entity);

    Audit audit= new Audit 
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        PrimaryKey = entity.Key, //This is not set because the State of the entity is still Added
    };

    Context.Audits.Add(audit);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is you can't do this in a distributed environment. You can't guarantee that the ID will be the same once the item is persisted.

Using client generated GUIDs does solve the problem. This is the approach I normally take, though let's not start a debate on that! You will mostly find the outcome is 50/50. Both have pros and cons. For your scenario, it works!

Comment: Don't cluster on a GUID column in the database, whatever you do

Comment: This would mean that all of the indexes in my database would have to be non-sequential GUIDs. I don't know how that will effect the performance

Comment: You need to weigh that up against the requirement. Is it a better option in your scenario to persist the item up front and have the database generate the sequential identity?