# How can I return an entity after I have just added it using EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following in my repository:

```
    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

My entitites all have a primary key that is an identity column. Once an entity is added I want to return that entity so I can then populate a grid and have the primary key be shown in the grid.

But how can I return the entity I added complete with details of the primary key?

FYI here's the code I use for adding in my service:

```
        try
        {
            var item = _uow.Tests.Add(Test);
            _uow.Commit();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Test>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
```

Would it be better if I left my repository without returning a value and instead added some code to the service?

Comment: are you not having separate methods in your repository to fetch the data back.for e.g getbyid,getall methods are very much standard on every repository

Comment: Yes I do have a getbyid and a getall. But after I have done the add I still don't know the id. The initial add was performed with an id of 0. Once it is inserted into the database the identity column changes this to the next id number in the sequence.

Comment: have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476826/obtain-primary-key-of-entity-whose-state-is-added

Comment: does _uow.Commit() save changes, and what is the value of Item.Id after that? If that looks OK, what happens when you open /api/Default/123 (where 123 is your new ID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should return the id. Check your mapping file for the `id` column of `item` - It should look something like this:

```
public class ItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemMap ()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // .....
    }
}
```

`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` is the setting that tells EF to get the newly generated sql identity value.